# Get NPM version tag using client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I was wondering if there is any way to get the latest version tag of a NPM package, using client-side JavaScript. I looked around for APIs and the like but I couldn't find anything that isn't deprecated.

However, I am pretty certain that it's possible to do, as [shields.io](http://shields.io/) does exactly that for multiple packages.

What I want to do is get the latest version tag as-is (e.g. `v1.2.5`) in either string or JSON format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call into the npm registry using your AJAX method of choice.

The URL for a given package is the base registry URL http://registry.npmjs.org with the package as the path i.e. http://registry.npmjs.org/styled-components.

If you check out that second URL you'll see a JSON document containing all the information you want for that package including the latest version.

example code:

```
const res = await fetch('http://registry.npmjs.org/styled-components');
const json = await res.json();
console.log(json['dist-tags'].latest) // latest distributed version
```

Comment: I've edited the last line of your code [in line with this suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348881/6650102). Let me know if this wasn't what you intended, but pretty sure it's just a typo (you can't get properties with `-` in them using the dot syntax)

Comment: Thanks @Aurora0001. That was indeed a typo on my part and I appreciate the amendment.

Comment: @JamieDixon No problem—you should thank DaftKauries (see the link in my previous comment) who spotted the issue!